# How to get Textinputs values in a Kivy App, added by using a For cycle in a Python 3.9 script?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, kivy, textinput

i have a Kivy App in a Python 3.9 script.
I add many Labels and Textinputs using a For cycle, so i have not the names of Textinputs.
is there a way to scan all my App, and get the Textinputs values?
P.s.: i already tried using Screenshot and Pytesseract, but i dont get all values.
O.s. Windows 10.
thanks

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
class app(App):
    def build(self):
        box=BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.labels=['label1: ','label2: ','label3: ','label4: ','label5: ']4
        self.values=['40','30','25','180','1500']
        grid=GridLayout(cols=2)
        c=0
        for text in self.labels:
            grid.add_widget(Label(text=text)
            grid.add_widget(TextInput(text=self.values[c]))
            c+=1
        box.add_widget(grid)
        button=Button(text='GET') #updating values in textinputs,before clicking button
        button.bind(on_press=self.get_new_values)
        box.add_widget(button())
        def get_new_values(self,instance):
            print('New values: '+self.values)
```

Answer (score 0):

before you create the TextInputs in a loop, create an empty list.

```
_my_list = []
```

inside the loop, append each one to this list.

```
textinput = TextInput(text='Hello world')
_my_list.append(textinput)
your_widget.append(textinput)
```

and then you can reference them like this

```
for one in _my_list:
    print(one.text)  # this prints the text value of one TextInput
```

or one could create an empty dictionary and add each item to the dictionary using a unique key.

Comment: thanks for help, but my problem is that i need values after update those

Comment: I populate window with labels and textinputs (using a for cycle), I update textinputs'  values, and I would get updated values after clicking a button.

Comment: one would call that code from the method you connect to the button.  it will help if you can amend your question with the code showing what you have tried.

Comment: just updated my post with my code